# Sequential Merge Sort in C

Tags: c, merge, mergesort

I am trying to re-write a recursive Merge Sort like

```
void MergeSort(int* data, int size){
  int half=size/2;
  if (size > 1) {
    MergeSort(data, half);
    MergeSort(data+half, half);
    Merge(data, size);
  }
}
```

in which

```
void Merge(int* data, int size){
  int cnt;
  int cntLow=0;
  int half=size/2;
  int cntHigh=half;
  int* sorted;

  sorted = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

  for (cnt=0; cnt<size; cnt++){
    if (cntLow == half) 
      sorted[cnt] = data[cntHigh++];
    else if (cntHigh == size)
      sorted[cnt] = data[cntLow++];
    else if (data[cntLow] <= data[cntHigh])
      sorted[cnt] = data[cntLow++];
    else
      sorted[cnt] = data[cntHigh++];
  }

  for (cnt=0; cnt<size; cnt++)
    data[cnt] = sorted[cnt];

  free(sorted);
}
```

to a non-recursive call. So I wrote the function

```
void MergeSort_NonRecursive(int* data, int size){
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=size; i>0; i=i/2){
        for (j=0; j<i; j++){
            Merge(data + j*size/i, size/i);
        }
    }
}
```

which apparently works for sequences of size $2^n$. However, when I run it in sequences of size different than $2^n$, it does not sort right, so in some point of `MergeSort_NonRecursive`, my code I must be mistaken.

So where did I do wrong (in `MergeSort_NonRecursive`)? (also, I need to use the `Merge` funcion).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the size is odd, you have `half + half + 1` elements. You should use `size - half` in one of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since size is an int, size/2 truncates your quotient.

e.g. if size=4, size/2 = 2. if size=5, size/2 = 2. if size=6, size/2 = 3.

So for a size of 5, you want the first MergeSort recursive call to operator on size/2 elements (i.e. the first 3), and the second call to operate on the remaining 2 elements.

You can say e.g.

```
int half = size/2; //size = 5: half = 2
int rest = size - half; //rest = 3
```

so:

```
void MergeSort(int* data, int size){
  int half=size/2;
  int rest = size-half;
  if (size > 1) {
    MergeSort(data, half);
    MergeSort(data+half, rest); //changed this line
    Merge(data, size);
  }
}
```

## Edit:

Looks like you changed the question slightly, after I posted. The general idea still stands: When you divide an int by another int, the quotient is truncated.

In your `MergeSort_NonRecursive`, you're dividing `int`s in a number of places, e.g. `i=i/2`, `j*size/i`, `size/i`. Pay attention to the values that you would get.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I updated the post trying to explain better. Do you have an idea of how to solve the problem of MergeSort_NonRecursive? I agree that the problem is similar, guess I looked to much to it that I cannot see anything.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you are trying to do a bottom-up merge sort (http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_merge_sort). So in the outer for-loop, you should start at `i=2` and multiply until you reach `size`, instead of starting at `size` and dividing.

Comment: I tried also the Bottom-Up approach, using the same definitions from your link, but did not work, at least using that `Merge` function. So I'm still trying the divider approach.